# PHP cURL return array

Tags: php, curl

I am creating a local software, where the user should be able to type in a key. This key will then be posted to a PHP-file on another server through cURL. I am new to cURL and know how to receive the posted key in the server's PHP-file and all that. However, I do not understand: how do you return variables without echoing them or print_r? I want the server's PHP to return an array, which the local file then will foreach-loop through. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [serialize()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is probably what you need

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the common and portable solution here is to use [json](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php)

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

and

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$res=json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true);
```

Comment: You prolly want to add `true` as 2nd param though

Comment: @DarkBee whether you want an object or an array from json_decode is personal preference, imo.

Comment: Yeah but OP wanted an array, that's why I mentioned this

Comment: @DarkBee oh, good point, added, thanks ^^